# AJAX insert in MySQL delay - non inserting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm programming kind of pool application - 
I have about 50 divs - 1 shown, 49 hidden. In every div there is a form with radiobuttons and after user clicks on radiobutton, JS calls AJAX - PHP request and inserts answer into MySQL. After success, next div is shown and so on...

Everything works fine, until i answer faster - about 3 question/second.

Then some answers stop being stored. For exmaple answers 1,2,4,6,7,10 are stored. 3,5,8,9 are missing...

How could i avoid it? It's really important to have consictency in answers.

Here is my JS

```
$('input[type=radio]').click(function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'assets/ajax/save_answer.php',
            data: {action: 'save_answer', question: currentQuestion, answer: $('input[name=answer-' + currentQuestion + ']:checked').val(), answer_pattern: 'agree-disagree', seconds: currentTime},
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (output) {
                if (output.success) {

                    $('.loading img').css("display", "none");


                        $('#' + currentQuestion).remove();
                        currentQuestion += currentQuestion;
                        $('#' + currentQuestion).show();


                } else {

                    alert("Answer wasn't stored");
                    $('.loading img').css("display", "none");
                }
            },
            error: function () {

                alert("Answer wasn't stored");
                $('.loading img').css("display", "none");
            }

        });
```

PHP function

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == "save_answer") {

$resp = new stdClass();


$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);


$user = $purifier->purify($_SESSION['user_id']);
$projekt = $purifier->purify($_SESSION['projekt_id']);
$otazka = $purifier->purify($_POST['question']);
$odpoved = $purifier->purify($_POST['answer']);
$answer_pattern = $purifier->purify($_POST['answer_pattern']);
$seconds = $purifier->purify($_POST['seconds']);

if(check_answer($answer_pattern, $odpoved)){

        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM odpovedi WHERE uzivatel = :uzivatel AND projekt = :projekt AND otazka = :otazka");
$stmt->bindParam(':uzivatel', $user);
$stmt->bindParam(':projekt', $projekt);
$stmt->bindParam(':otazka', $otazka);
$stmt->execute();
$answers_count = count($stmt->fetchAll());

if ($answers_count != 1) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO odpovedi (uzivatel, projekt, otazka, odpoved, seconds) VALUES (:uzivatel, :projekt, :otazka, :odpoved, :seconds) ");
    $stmt->bindParam(':uzivatel', $user);
    $stmt->bindParam(':projekt', $projekt);
    $stmt->bindParam(':otazka', $otazka);
    $stmt->bindParam(':odpoved', $odpoved);
    $stmt->bindParam(':seconds', $seconds);

    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM odpovedi WHERE uzivatel = :uzivatel AND projekt = :projekt AND otazka = :otazka");
$stmt->bindParam(':uzivatel', $user);
$stmt->bindParam(':projekt', $projekt);
$stmt->bindParam(':otazka', $otazka);
$stmt->execute();
$answer_inserted = count($stmt->fetchAll());

    if ($answer_inserted < 1) {
        $resp->success = false;
    } else {
        $resp->success = true;
    }
}else{
    $resp->success = true;
}



}else{
    $resp->success = false;
}
```

}

print json_encode($resp);

At least alert should be shown, right? But it is not...
Thank you,

Tomáš

Comment: update your question with php code as well

Comment: Note : use   `alert("Answer wasn't stored");`

Comment: You should escape the single quote character in the alert function: `alert('Answer wasn\'t stored');`

Comment: Right, i edited alerts here on page, becuase im from czech republic and alerts were in my lang, so i did it just for clariry purposes.

Comment: First of all you must see where it fails so add error reporting on every step: if ($stmt = $db->prepare()) { if ($stmt->bindparam( You could bind all of them in the same time)) { if ($stmt->execute()) { echo 'Success!' } else { echo $db->error, E_USER_ERROR; } echo $db->error, E_USER_ERROR; } else { echo $db->error, E_USER_ERROR; }

Answer (score 1):

Change your alert to

```
alert('Answer wasn\'t stored');
```

or,

```
alert("Answer wasn't stored");
```

Comment: I know, in my original code it's as you wrote. It's just a typo here on page, i  translated alerts into english

Answer (score 0):

Try option `async: false` in ajax options.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

As the option name says make asynchronous false, i.e it will wait for ajax to complete before showing next div/element(whatever is in your success).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've found solution by myself.

I didn't disable radiobutons when one of them was clicked. Because of that - another AJAX function was called and interrupted the previous one.

Now when I disable buttons after click and enable them after ajax succeed is everything fine.

Thank you for your help.